# Name for a flour-free onion sauce

Tags: onions, low-carb

I came across this in the context of low-carb chicken pie filling, in other words without a flour/roux base. Is there a name for a sauce that starts with low & slow-cooked onions?

Asking for a friend ... really ;-)

Thanks.

Comment: Are there ingredients in it? (Sounds tasty, but all that comes to mind is French onion soup!)

Comment: This was: soubise + white wine from chicken reduction + stock + spinach + shredded poached chicken thighs. In a pie.

Comment: Hmmm . . .The small amount of flour to make a roux to thicken a sauce will be nothing in comparison to the amount of flour in the pastry of a pie.   Wouldn't it be better to replace the pastry? What about using sliced aubergine(egg plant), courgettes(zucchini), mushrooms . . . ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A soubise is a classic french onion-based sauce.  Really it is just slow cooked onions with a bechamel added.  Of course, bechamel has flour in it to thicken.  However, I have seen recipes where the bechamel is replaced with heavy cream.  For example, [here](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2015/03/roasted-chicken-curry-soubise-onion-sauce-recipe.html), onion, cream, and vadouvan spice are blended together to make a flour-free soubise.  It would make a terrific pot pie filling!